# What is the opposite of Loan?

Tags: finance

When I take 100$ from Joe with the intention to return it later, Joe is the lender and I am a borrower. This act called Loan from **my perspective**.
I loaned a money from Joe. Joe lent me 100$.

How this act called from **Joe perspective**?

When Joe gives me 100$ with the intention to get it back later, how is this called from Joes perspective? Is this also a Loan?

Comment: You *borrowed* money from Joe. Joe *lent* you money.

Comment: @Drew true, but the act it self. From my perspective its a Loan. What about Joes perspective?

Comment: It's also a loan from Joe's perspective, a loan being money that both parties agree should be returned to to lender

Comment: The act is *borrowing* or *lending*, depending on the point of view. The thing that is loaned is the *loan*, as @SConroy has mentioned.

Comment: alrightythen ... answers provided!

Comment: @SConroy You  should post an answer.

Comment: Look up the word *loan* in a good dictionary.

Comment: joe makes an *investment*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP's question asks what the act is from Joe's perspective, but from the comments I get that the noun is also wanted.

As far as the verb goes, Joe either lends or loans you the money.

[lend](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/lend?s=t) verb

> to grant the use of (something) on condition that it or its equivalent
>   will be returned.

[loan](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/loan?s=t)
verb (used with object)

```
to make a loan of; lend: Will you loan me your umbrella?
to lend (money) at interest.
```

verb (used without object)

```
to make a loan or loans; lend.
```

The *noun*, what is being lent/borrowed is a **loan** from both persectives, a loan being money that both parties agree should be returned to the lender.

> noun
>
> the act of lending; a grant of the temporary use of something: the loan of       a book.
>   something lent or furnished on condition of being returned, especially a sum of money lent at interest: a $1000 loan at 10 percent
>   interest.